# .htacess redirect directory to one domain and subdirectory to different domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Having trouble creating/finding the correct Rewrite rules for this...

```
domain1.com/abc -> domain2.com/crazylongurl
domain1.com/abc/def -> domain3.com/differentcrazylongurl
```

I currently have

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /abc domain2.com/crazylongurl
```

And that works. But I can't get the /def subdirectory to go to a different url. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I didn't know about negative lookaheads. So, in the `domain.com/abc` directory, I put an .htaccess file with this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /abc(?!/def) domain2.com/crazylongurl
```

And in the `domain.com/abc/def` directory, I put an .htaccess file with this in it:

```
ReWriteEngine On
Redirect /abd/def domain3.com/differentcrazylongurl
```